# objects parsing in html component in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to use an object in @input parameter in the html.
for example:

```
<app-home [param]="user.salary"></app-home>
```

but the type of my user is something like that:

```
user:Person=new Employee();
```

my classes are:

```
export class Person {
constructor(public name:string){}
}
export class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(public name:string,
        public salary:number){
            super(name);
        }
}
```

how do I parse the user in the @input parameter to Employee?

I tried to do so:

```
<app-home [param]="(user as Employee).salary"></app-home>
```

but I get an error. so how can I do it?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. As it is currently written I am not sure what you are asking, what you are actually trying (the real code), or what the problem is.

Comment: Please elaborate the actual and expected result you want. We will not get any clear idea about the problem.

Comment: I edited my question now and I hope it's ok. if not, what do I have to do to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the complete object, and as I may assume you're already defining it, change the param class to handle to object

```
class HomeComponent{
    @Input() param: Employee;
}
```

then pass the object instead of a simgle property

```
<home-component [param]="user"></home-component>
```

This way you're getting the full component and you can now access and manipulate all it's properties.

If you have an object in **home-component** that you want to define by passing the *user* to it, try using a *setter*, like this

```
class homeComponent{

    private _user:Employee;

    @Input()
    set param(data) {
        this._user = data;
    }

}
```

Or you can destructure it to handle easily each property and assign individually

```
class homeComponent{

    private _user:Employee;

    @Input()
    set param({name, salary}) {
        this._user = new Employee(name, salary)
    }

}
```

---

If your **User** object is missing *salary* and you want to assign it after passing to the **HomeComponent**, you can try this

```
class homeComponent{

    private _employee:Employee;
    private _salary:number = 2000;

    @Input()
    set param(data) {
        this._employee = new Employee({...data, salary: this._salary})
    }

}
```

This way, you're getting your entire object, and trigger the setter to complete it's definition by adding the `salary` property;

Comment: first, my salary property is not string - it's a number. second, I need to parse my whole user to Employee and not a specific property.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding at all what you're trying to acheive, but just updated my anwser. Hope any of these examples help you.